# How to get 0% inflation eosio chain?

Tags: economics

Would I just call this with all 0 values?

```
setinflation( int64_t annual_rate, int64_t inflation_pay_factor, int64_t votepay_factor )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just need to set `annual_rate` to 0.

The cleos command would be:

```
cleos push action eosio setinflation '[0,50000,40000]' -p eosio
```